# How to include ManyToMany Fields in DjangoRestFramework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class EntityServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields =  '__all__'


class EntityCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    entity_service = EntityServiceSerializerThrough(read_only=True, source='serviceschedule_set', many=True)

        class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = '__all__'
```

Model looks like this

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    entity_service = models.ManyToManyField(Service, through='ServiceSchedule')

class ServiceSchedule(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Service(models.Model):
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=128, unique=True, null=False, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

I have these serializers (there are more fields in entity model, but they're irrelevant since the only problem i have is with the Many2Many)
The thing is, when i put in body "entity_service": [1,2] in the response i still get = []. Even though i have in my database Services with pk 1,2,3,4.

Do you know how can i make it work?

Comment: You have `read_only=True` and unecessary `source='serviceschedule_set'` parameter in your `EntityCreateSerializer`. Even when you will fix this you will have another problem (you cant put `entity_service` by ids - use SlugRelatedField instead for input and `EntityServiceSerializerThrough` serializer for output)

Answer (score 0):

Try it without a source as the field name is the same as the model field name

```
class EntityCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    entity_service = EntityServiceSerializerThrough(read_only=True, many=True)

        class Meta:
        model = Entity
        fields = '__all__'
```